# Read CSV with non-ascii character set in pandas and then store in PGSQL

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv, ascii

Is there any ways so that I can process non ascii character set reading in pandas df from a csv and after that store in postgresql from pandas df?

I want to keep all the information intact while storing in postgresql.

Comment: Please, share what have you tried to do so far and paste your code. Other people will not do your work for you, but we are glad to help. Also, please clarify your question. What do you mean by process non-ascii characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe your biggest issue is reading the non-ASCII character. However, this has been solved here

https://gist.github.com/glennzw/bc9cdca912bd08d30f66211d538c293d

The second part is then to export this csv to `PGSQL`. Your question doesn't say which tool you want to use. I'll assume python. I would do this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://............')
```

and

```
df.to_sql(YourTable, if_exists = '**', con=engine)
```

where `** = append` or `replace`